# How can I check if an element still exists in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element, exists

How can I check if an element still exists in the DOM?

```html
<div id="parent">
  ...
  <div class="my-class"></div>
</div>
```

```js
let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
let myElement = parent.getElementsByClassName('my-class')[0];
parent.remove();

function stillExists(element) {
   // check if element still exists in DOM
}

stillExists(myElement) // should be false
```

Comment: `document.contains(myElement)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Answer (score 5):

Simply do

```js
document.contains(myElement)
```